# How can i call a custom method on submission of a custom plugin post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, callbacks

I have registered a custom post type .On submission of that page/ post  can i call a custom method . How ?

Can i add a method in plugin file and will it call on post type submission by ACF or any other way in the admin side?

Comment: Can you try to explain again what the problem is, what are you trying to do and what you have tried/investigated? It is quite unclear for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save_post is an action triggered whenever a post or page is created or updated, which could be from an import, post/page edit form, xmlrpc, or post by email. The data for the post is stored in $_POST, $_GET or the global $post_data, depending on how the post was edited. For example, quick edits use $_POST.

Since this action is triggered right after the post has been saved, you can easily access this post object by using get_post($post_id)

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post